# How to deposit token-pair in pool (about uniswap code)

Tags: ethereum

I am studying uniswapV2 contract code. And I deployed contracts on ropsten network. then I created a pool by createPool method. I wonder how to deposit tokens in the created pool contract. The created pool is a pair of DAI tokens and UNISWAP tokens. Below is the way I made a pool.

```
const pool = await FACTORY.methods.createPair(DAI_ADDR, UNI_ADDR).send({from: "0x53D18059f51eB2D1B73b7DA41f971fcF0c45f122"});
```

return pool address is 0xd6Ca8d671E7e96ED28F67cb196b1056EbDb550d9

here is code repository link.
https://github.com/Uniswap/v2-core

How to deposit a token-pair by contract method? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The phrase you're looking for is "add liquidity" (and the opposite action is "remove liquidity"). You deposit the underlying tokens and mint the LP (liquidity provider) tokens representing your stake in the pair contract.

You can provide liquidity through the router's function `addLiquidity()` ([docs](https://docs.uniswap.org/protocol/V2/reference/smart-contracts/router-02#addliquidity)).

Comment: I really appreciate your help. I've tried many times to add liquidity to the pool using the add Liquidity function in the link you sent, but unfortunately without success. I thought about the reason and realized that I had to approve the token before providing liquidity. So, I executed the approve function not only DAI token contract but also UNI 
token contract (using the Router02 contract as the operator), and tried the addLiquidity function, but I am still receiving only "execution reverted" message.

Comment: If you know of an example code that actually uses the addLiquidity function or the procedure of supplying liquidity with the UniswapV2 contract code, could you please let me know? I'm really desperate. No worries, but thank you.

Comment: There are few potential causes of the issue, unfrotunately the error message is too generic to tell what exactly went wrong. From not approved sufficient amount of any of the tokens to the router, to an incorrectly set deadline param, possibly an issue with the underlying token contract or an insufficient amount of the underlying token that you're trying to send, ... I don't know any sources from the top of my head, but was able to google [this snippet](https://gist.github.com/markusait/6913c286116f18761165e7de4ca021dc) at least. Hope it helps.